# how to download google drive file in angular

Tags: angularjs, google-drive-api

I have an angular app which uses a google drive picker to allow the user to select a file to download.  In the google developer credentials area, I have the javascript origins and referrers set up to use localhost:3000 so the picker opens just fine.  However, from that point, I can't seem to get the selected file.  Here's the angular code where it tries to download the file.

```
$scope.$watchCollection('googleFiles', function (newGoogleFiles) {
    if (newGoogleFiles.length > 0) {
        $scope.filename = newGoogleFiles[newGoogleFiles.length - 1].name;
        $scope.fileUrl = newGoogleFiles[newGoogleFiles.length - 1].url;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get($scope.fileUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
            .success(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

Instead of getting a file I get - XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/a/##############/edit?usp%3Ddrive_web&ltmpl=docs. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I'm guessing I need to set up something in the $http.get request for the file, but I have no idea what.  Anyone have any idea?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're dealing with is "CORS" (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is something that has to be set on the server. You can probably log into google app settings and tell it what "origins" it can expect (ex: localhost, www.yourwebsite.com).

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of that.  As I originally said, I already set up localhost in the credentials within the google developer section.  If they weren't set up correctly then the picker wouldn't load and allow me to pick a file - which it does.  It's just when I try to download the selected file that I get that error.  What I notice is that it says the origin is 'null' in the error message instead of localhost.  So, is there something I need to do on the $http.get to set the origin there?

Comment: have you used a tool like fiddler2 to see your request and response headers?

Comment: No, but I'm on a mac.  In chrome dev tools I can see the response/request headers.  Is there something specific I should look for?

Comment: in the network tab, select the request that is failing. On the right you should see the "Headers" tab. Look for the Origin header in the request and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response. You can then isolate the problem.

Comment: Again, the origin is null.  How do I isolate that?

Comment: you don't even know if the problem is on the client or the server. what i'm trying to tell you is that you have to figure that out first.

Comment: If the origin is null on the request headers, doesn't that mean the issue is on the client?  I would expect that if it's an issue with the server then the origin issue would be seen in the response headers, not the request headers.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured out most of the issue.  I was using the url returned by the google drive picked file when I should have been using the id.  That has taken care of the CORS issue.